# Chemiluminescence of luminol

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution

Recently I have tried to perform an experiment with luminol and hydrogen peroxide (with potassium ferricyanide as the catalyst). Upon googling, I found two ways to conduct this experiment and was wondering which way is more suitable (because I have limited amounts of luminol and do not want to fail the experiment and waste luminol).

1st way: Preparing an alkaline stock solution of luminol and potassium ferricyanide and another stock solution consisting of hydrogen peroxide only.

2nd way: Preparing an alkaline stock solution of luminol  and another stock solution consisting of hydrogen peroxide and potassium ferricyanide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://pubs-acs-org.ezproxy1.lib.asu.edu/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed053p548) they replace the ferricyanide for bleach, but the description does say that the luminol solution is stable in base for up to three weeks. So I would follow your 2nd way.